# Regularised value of cardinality of non trivial Zeta zeros:

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, regularization

This is a straight forward question so apologies in advance

Consider the following sums:

> $$\sum_k1_{\rho_k}$$

> $$\sum_k{\rho_k}$$

(i.e. first sum counts non trivial zeros of Zeta function)

> I want to know if regularised value exists for such infinite sums as there are various explicit formulae containing sum of functions of Zeta zeros ( ex. Guinand-Weil explicit formula).